# Select ng-options raising $digest() iterations reached error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a SELECT element defined as so:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" 
    ng-options="composer.Name for composer in composerList track by composer.Name | orderBy:'Name'" 
    ng-model="selectedComposer">
```

`composerList` and `selectedComposer` are created in the controller as so:

```
AlbumService.getComposerList().then(function (data) {
    $scope.composerList = data; //data comes from a REST response in the service
    $scope.selectedComposer = $scope.album.Composer;
});
```

The structure of `composer` is simply `Id` and `Name` properties but it will expand in future.

The problem is with the `SELECT` element above. It is throwing a number of `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` errors.

```
    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function() { return ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue); }","newVal":["J","o","h","n"," ","W","i","l","i","a","m","s"],"oldVal":["J","o","h","n"," ","W","i","l","i","a","m","s"]},{"msg":"fn: interceptedExpression","newVal":138,"oldVal":121}],[{"msg":"fn: function() { return ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue); }","newVal":["J","o","h","n"," ","W","i","l","i","a","m","s"],"oldVal":"..."},{"msg":"fn: interceptedExpression","newVal":155,"oldVal":138}],[{"msg":"fn: function() { return ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue); }","newVal":["J","o","h","n"," ","W","i","l","i","a","m","s"],"oldVal":"..."},{"msg":"fn: interceptedExpression","newVal":172,"oldVal":155}],[{"msg":"fn: function() { return ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue); }","newVal":["J","o","h","n"," ","W","i","l","i","a","m","s"],"oldVal":"..."},{"msg":"fn: interceptedExpression","newVal":189,"oldVal":172}],[{"msg":"fn: function() { return ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue); }","newVal":["J","o","h","n"," ","W","i","l","i","a","m","s"],"oldVal":"..."},{"msg":"fn: interceptedExpression","newVal":206,"oldVal":189}]]
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function()%20%7B%20return%20ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.%24viewValue)%3B%20%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22J%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22h%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22%20%22%2C%22W%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22l%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22m%22%2C%22s%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%5B%22J%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22h%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22%20%22%2C%22W%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22l%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22m%22%2C%22s%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20interceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A138%2C%22oldVal%22%3A121%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function()%20%7B%20return%20ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.%24viewValue)%3B%20%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22J%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22h%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22%20%22%2C%22W%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22l%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22m%22%2C%22s%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22...%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20interceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A155%2C%22oldVal%22%3A138%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function()%20%7B%20return%20ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.%24viewValue)%3B%20%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22J%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22h%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22%20%22%2C%22W%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22l%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22m%22%2C%22s%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22...%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20interceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A172%2C%22oldVal%22%3A155%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function()%20%7B%20return%20ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.%24viewValue)%3B%20%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22J%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22h%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22%20%22%2C%22W%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22l%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22m%22%2C%22s%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22...%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20interceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A189%2C%22oldVal%22%3A172%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function()%20%7B%20return%20ngOptions.getTrackByValue(ngModelCtrl.%24viewValue)%3B%20%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22J%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22h%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22%20%22%2C%22W%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22l%22%2C%22i%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22m%22%2C%22s%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22...%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20interceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A206%2C%22oldVal%22%3A189%7D%5D%5D
    at angular.js:138
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18625)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18945)
    at done (angular.js:12799)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:13056)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12961)
```

I don't know why these errors are being raised. Whatever the solution is, I need to retain setting the `selectedComposer` variable from the `album` variable and I would prefer to keep the `SELECT` a list of composer objects rather than a list of strings of the composer name.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others who might see my question in future, I did more research and the solution is simple. The track by part of ng-options should be moved to the end of the string.

```
ng-options="composer.Name for composer in composerList | orderBy:'Name' track by composer.Name"
```

Comment: it wasn't explicit to me that I had to use track by in the end of the statement. solved my issue. thank you for sharing your solution